# Searching by multiple possible attributes for one search field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I have a search field that can search for multiple different attributess.  For example, be able to search for an associated models attribute and the self attribute in one search field?

I want to allow the user to search by what they want to search by, as most websites have this feature...

**I have:**

**Model:**

```
  def self.user_search(search)
    joins(:shipments).where(shipments: { id: Shipment.where(shipping_label: ShippingLabel.where(tracking_number: "#{search.downcase}")) })
    joins(:shipping_address).where(shipping_addresses: { id: ShippingAddress.where(shipping_address_final: ShippingAddressFinal.where(address1: "#{search.downcase}")) })
  end
```

This doesn't work.  each `joins` works on it's own, but together only the last one will ever work.

How can I combine these to work?

Overall, I will be implementing many more possible search attributes but starting with just these 2 will lead me in the correct way.

I have tried using `||`

This only allows the first `join` to work.

Using:

```
def self.user_search(search)
  tracking_number = joins(:shipments).where(shipments: { id: Shipment.where(shipping_label: ShippingLabel.where(tracking_number: "#{search.downcase}")) })
  address1 = joins(:shipping_address).where(shipping_addresses: { id: ShippingAddress.where(shipping_address_final: ShippingAddressFinal.where(address1: "#{search.downcase}")) })
  tracking_number.or(address1)
end
```

gives an error upon search:

`ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) approach is a step in the right direction. The reason you get the error is because the structures are incompatible. Meaning that they should generate the same SQL `FROM` statement. Currently one query is joining `shipments` while the other is joining `shipping_address`.

```
# statement #1 (tracking_number)
FROM model INNER JOIN shipments ON ...

# statement #2 (address1)
FROM model INNER JOIN shipping_addresses ON ...
```

You should do the joins first. Both statements should have both joins to make them compatible.

```
scope = joins(:shipments).joins(:shipping_address)
tracking_number = scope.where(shipments: { id: Shipment.where(shipping_label: ShippingLabel.where(tracking_number: "#{search.downcase}")) })
address1 = scope.where(shipping_addresses: { id: ShippingAddress.where(shipping_address_final: ShippingAddressFinal.where(address1: "#{search.downcase}")) })
tracking_number.or(address1)
```

The only thing changed in the above statement is that both your queries now join both tables, making them compatible since they generate the same SQL `FROM` statement.

Resulting in:

```
# statement #1 (tracking_number)
FROM model 
  INNER JOIN shipments ON ...
  INNER JOIN shipping_addresses ON ...

# statement #2 (address1)
FROM model 
  INNER JOIN shipments ON ...
  INNER JOIN shipping_addresses ON ...
```

Comment: I'm about tot try this but if it matters I am using Postgres

Comment: @uno The database type shouldn't matter. I've added the resulting generated SQL to better explain myself.

Comment: This seems to work only if a tracking_number is present.  For orders that don't yet have a tracking numbers, I search the address1, and the order doesn't result.  After I add tracking, i repeat and it will result under the address1 search.  Is there something making it happen this way?

Comment: @uno Use [`left_joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) instead of [`joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins).